# Angular $scope value won't show up on a page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am starting to learn Angular and tried to repeat the "To do list" task they have on the homepage. However, I am stuck in the very beginning:

http://codepen.io/Deka87/pen/grGWqQ

Template

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <h2>{{totalItems}}</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.totalItems = 4;
}
```

I seem to do the very same thing, however it doesn't work. What's wrong?

Comment: Kindly watch this once, before you implement `ng-repeat` http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js/level/1/section/3/video/1

Comment: You have not declared a module, i.e. your app. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you must import the `angular` library, then instantiate your `app` and finally create your *controller*, this way:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('TodoCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.totalItems = 4;
  });
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
  <div>
    <h2>{{totalItems}}</h2>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I recommend you to check this: [What is a Module?](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module)

Comment: Thanks, it works this way. I wonder why they don't have this in their video.

Comment: Glad it helps, what video did you watch?

Answer (score 0):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EywXXQ Here is the fork of your codepen with the code working.

- You need to import the angular script
- Need to create an angular app like this
- Inject the app in your html using ng-app
- Create a controller and inject it in your html using ng-controller

  ```
   angular.module('app', []).controller('TodoCtrl',
    function ($scope) {
     $scope.totalItems = 4;
   });
  ```

> Go through these tutorials that will help you understand it better
>
> [Tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial)